# OpenCV using Windows Form keeps on throwing exceptions about stack overflowing

Tags: opencv, c++-cli, windows-forms-designer

I've been writing a program and every time I close my form it throws an exception saying my stack overflowed on the line which closes the background worker...

I have faced this problem for some time now, I've tried googling the problem but I haven't come up with any desired solution yet...

My troubleshooting guesses are as follows :

1. Pictures in picturebox takes up resources and are not cleared when aborting program
2. Background Worker is still busy

Here is my code, thanks in advance !

---

> **Elements**
>
> Picturebox called *videobox*
>   Button called *btnOpenCamera_Click*
>   Button called *btnCloseCamera_Click*
>   Label called *backgroundworkerStatus*

> **Variables**
>
> Global
>
> ```
> Mat videoFrame;
> VideoCapture video(0);
> ```
>
> Private
>
> ```
> bool flag_cameraStatus = true;
> bool flag_backgroundworkerStatus = false;
> ```

> **Functions**
>
> private: System::Void MainForm_FormClosing
>
> ```
> // this event is triggered when application is closing
>
> video.release();
>
> /* Exception is thrown here "System.StackOverflowException" */
> backgroundWorker->CancelAsync();
>
> if (backgroundWorker->IsBusy == false) {
>     checkBackgroundworkerStatus();
>     this->Close();
> }
> else {
>     MessageBox::Show("Backgroundworker not aborted");
>     e->Cancel = true;
> }
> ```
>
> private: System::Void btnOpenCamera_Click
>
> ```
> // this is a button for turning on camera
>
> flag_cameraStatus = true;
> backgroundWorker->RunWorkerAsync();
> ```
>
> private: System::Void btnCloseCamera_Click
>
> ```
> // this is a button for turning off camera
>
> flag_cameraStatus = false;
> videoBox->Image = nullptr;
> ```
>
> int openCamera()
>
> ```
> // this is a button for turning off camera
>
> if (!video.isOpened()) {
>     MessageBox::Show("Cannot Find Camera!");
>     return -1;
> }
>
> while (flag_camera) {
>
>   video >> videoFrame;
>   if (videoFrame.empty()) {
>         break;
>   }
>
>   /* These lines of code converts Opencv mat to bitmap for picturebox to display */
>   System::Drawing::Graphics^ graphics = videoBox->CreateGraphics();
>   System::IntPtr ptr(videoFrame.ptr());
>   System::Drawing::Bitmap^ b = gcnew System::Drawing::Bitmap(videoFrame.cols, videoFrame.rows, videoFrame.step, System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb, ptr);
>   System::Drawing::RectangleF rect(0, 0, videoBox->Width, videoBox->Height);
>   graphics->DrawImage(b, rect);
>
>   /* Was wondering if I need these lines of code below */
>   /* delete graphics;                                  */
>
> if (flag_camera == false) {
>     videoBox->Image = nullptr;
>     return 0;
> }
> ```
>
> void checkBackgroundworkerStatus()
>
> ```
> // this function is used to check if backgroundworker is busy
> // it will identify the status via the backcolor of label backgroundworkerStatus
>
> if(backgroundWorker->IsBusy==true)
> backgroundworkerStatus->BackColor = Color::Green;
> else
> backgroundworkerStatus->BackColor = SystemColors::Control;
> ```
>
> private: System::Void backgroundWorker_DoWork
>
> ```
> // this event is triggered when background worker is working
>
> if (backgroundWorker->CancellationPending == false) {
>     checkBackgroundworkerStatus();
>     openCamera();
> }
> else {
>     this->backgroundWorker->CancelAsync();
> }
> ```
>
> private: System::Void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted
>
> ```
> // this event is triggered when background worker is done working
>
> checkBackgroundworkerStatus();
> ```

---

**Some Last Notes...**

I did set my

```
WorkerSupportsCancellation = true
WorkerReportsProgress = true
```

Comment: Why do my posts get down-voted every time ? Sigh...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem,add a delay to DoWork

private: System::Void backgroundWorker1_DoWork

> `using namespace System::Threading`
>   
>   `/* your DoWork tasks */`
>   
>   `Thread::Sleep(50)`

**Note**

Thread::Sleep counts in milliseconds, you can change to the number you want according to your cameras fps.
My laptop webcam is approx. 15 fps, which is 66.66 ms per frames, the sleep time should be >= this ms/frame but I have no problems running it with a delay of only 50ms.